# Python (SublimeText3) se cuelga

Tags: python

Como podrá apreciarse, soy nuevo en todo esto.
Mi problema es que, mientras intento practicar con Python por ejemplo programando el juego PONG a siguiendo un tutorial, la ventana que he sacado se cuelga, no responde o no se actualiza a pesar de seguir escribiendo código.
El prompt a veces desaparece, pudiendo seguir escribiendo pero sin ejecutar nada.
Siento si estoy siendo poco concreto. Gracias por el tiempo.

```
>>> import turtle
>>> wn=turtleScreen()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'turtleScreen' is not defined
>>> wn=turtle.Screen()
>>> wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Title")
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: Entendido, espero que se comprenda mejor ahora. Al final, el prompt desaparece y no puedo seguir corriendo el código que escribo.